# Simple array element substraction in VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

`all(i,k,c)-all(i,k+1,c)=aa`

VBA returns "expected=" error and highlights the "-"

Why can't I subtract perfectly legit values from each other?

Comment: what exactly do you have, and what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

`aa = all(i,k,c) - all(i,k+1,c)`

Comment: haha this worked. What a noob i am...

Answer (score 0):

Your statement is ambiguous. As `all(i,k,c)` and `all(i,k+1,c)` are different elements, it's equivalent to writing

```
x - y = aa
```

But this does not assign a unique value to either `x` or `y`. Hence the error.

If you want to return the difference between `all(i, k + 1, c)` and `all(i, k, c)` then write

```
aa = all(i, k + 1, c) - all(i, k, c)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer but how can i achieve this without assigning a unique varible to each and every single element of these arrays?  I mean there are 1000+ elements in these...

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to achieve. Would you mind elaborating in your question?

Comment: oh i am so silly, i forgot that it assigns right value to left one. Thanks for your patience.